# How to reliably use a Guava LoadingCache when requiring persistence?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I store references in my application, e.g. (key) number => (value) name, usually for a short time (suitable to keep in memory), but sometimes for a longer time which requires me to persist it to DB (to survive application restarts and memory constraints). Earlier we always persisted to DB, but now I want to use LoadingCache as a performance enhancement as references usually are short-lived (no need to persist).

In my application I store references, e.g. key 123 => value "Paul".
I use a LoadingCache with expiry set to 45 seconds with the reasoning that if value has not been used for 45 seconds I want to persist it to DB (using a RemovalListener) so that a request for key 123 a day later from cache should return "Paul" using `.load()` from DB (as it's not in cache).

My question concerns that maintenance isn't guaranteed to happen immediately and that I don't understand when `onRemoval()`actually is called and how to solve my problem reliably.

Example flow:
1. Input is received saying that key 123 corresponds to value "Paul" which I `.put()` to my LoadingCache
2. Whenever data is used (often within 10-20 seconds) it's fetched via `.get()` and thereafter removed with `.invalidate()`

The LoadingCache has a RemovalListener that `onRemoval()` persist expired entries (checked with `.wasEvicted()` to avoid explicitly invalidated records) to DB table.

My problem is with how the cache's cleanup happens.
Example:
I add a value which should expire 45 seconds later.
If I try to `.get()` it 50 seconds later it is not returned to me as it has expired, but as I understand it from my tests there is no guarantee that value is removed using `onRemoval()` yet either before my `.get()` returns? This means I have not persisted it to DB so my load() method cannot find the value either (until later when `onRemoval()` actually has happened). So, I've lost my value when I need it which is not acceptable.

Am I trying to use LoadingCache for something it was not intended for or is there any way I can make it suit my needs? Or perhaps there is an alternative suggestion / solution?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Instead of using a write-back cache, always write to the database and cache what is in use. Guava's cache has a `cleanUp` to perform maintenance work on-demand, as otherwise it is amortized on calling threads. In your case the on-demand may still lead to race conditions, so storing will always be safer.

Comment: This is what we've previously done, writing everything to database. But as a matter of fact only 5% of all data is needed in more than 45 seconds so it makes a lot of sense to cache in memory instead for performance reasons and only write to database if it is really needed. Maybe also worth mentioning that each cache entry only is used maximum three times, but most often only two times.

Comment: these cases work brilliantly well in redis, since you often need multiple servers anyways, and the data store can expire entries automatically. Guava's Cache was not designed for write-back, where you probably would want a write prior the removal to avoid races. I can think of poor hacks (like a secondary map), but you'll run into limitations regardless once you use multiple servers. A data store designed for your type of traffic will probably be useful in many areas of your application.

Comment: For the foreseeable future this application will be self-contained and even if it would run on several servers the instances should run in isolation. Therefor I'd rather like to avoid external dependencies like Redis. I've been thinking about hacks like a secondary map as you mention but thought there must be a battle-tested solution to this problem already out there.  My main language is not Java so perhaps there exist an alternative to Guava I am not aware that I can look further into? Thanks a lot for your help, appreciated!

Comment: None that are elegant and it sounds like the simpler the better. In that case a background thread that scans the cache every minute to expire entries and write them out may be the easiest to maintain.

Comment: I agree, simpler is indeed better and I've googled a lot to only find way overkill solutions. Your suggestion actually brings me to a concern I originally had. Does onRemoval() get called before an element actually is removed? One idea I had was to switch from timebased expiry to size-expiry (say 10k elements). If onRemoval() will be called and block any .get() on the same key while running I have the time to persist and keep my cache + DB persist consistent.

Comment: The listener is called after removal. If you don't need much concurrency then a lock and a simpler data structure that you have full control over should work well. LinkedHashMap can be used as an LRU cache and may fit your requirements.